# Linux system calls vs C lib functions

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I have bit bit of confusion regarding these two so here are my questions;

The Linux man-pages project lists all these functions:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/

Looking at `recvfrom` as an example, this function exists both as a Linux system call as well as a C library function. Their documentation seems different but they are both reachable using `#include <sys/socket.h>`.
I don't understand their difference?

I also thought systems calls are defined using hex values which can be implemented in assembly directly, their list is here:
https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/

However I cannot find `recvfrom` in the above link. I'm a bit confused between Linux system calls vs C lib functions at this point!

Edit: To add to the questions, alot of functions are under (3) but not (2), i.e `clean`. Does this mean these are done by C runtime directly without relying on system calls and the underlying OS?

Comment: I guess that the source of your confusion is that you have installed the [`manpages-posix-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/manpages-posix-dev) or similar package, which is installing its manpage formatted versions of the standard spec in the section 3.

Comment: they're there because you installed them, and POSIX/susv4 has no idea of "system calls", only of "interfaces". The standard makes no difference between a library function like `isatty()` or a syscall wrapper like `read()`.

Comment: @josh Check `posix_madvise(3)`/`madvise(2)` and operation `POSIX_MADV_DONTNEED`/`MADV_DONTNEED`. Kinda explains the relationship between two sections.

Comment: I didn't install anything tho, Im just looking at the web page above.

Comment: that syscalls.kernelgrok web page is about the i386, which is now history. the [`syscall(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) and [`syscalls(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) manpages on your system have more serious info, including a nice table with how the arguments are passed and which instruction is used on each platform supported by linux.

Comment: *sigh...* If only the "lacks minimal understanding" close reason was brought back.

Comment: @mosvy i386 is still used (although the 386 itself is not supported anymore, only the 486 and onwards) in some cases, such as where low memory usage is needed (8-byte pointers have quite a bit of overhead when you're dealing with complex tasks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, understand that that C functions and system calls are ***two completely different things***.

System calls not wrapped in the C library *must* be called through the `syscall` function. One example of such a call is `gettid`.

To create a `gettid` system call wrapper with `syscall`, do this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t gettid(void)
{
    pid_t tid = (pid_t)syscall(SYS_gettid);
    return tid;
}
```

Here's an excerpt from the NOTES section of the man-page, which explicitly states that this function is not defined within the C library:

> NOTES
>   Glibc does not provide a wrapper for this system call; call it using syscall(2).

---

`recvfrom` is a C library wrapper around a system call.
Everything in section (2) is a system call. Everything in section (3) is not. Everything in section (3) (with a few notable exceptions, such as `getumask`) has a definition in the C library. About half of everything in section (2) does not have a definition (or wrapper) within the C library (with the exception of functions mandated by POSIX, and some other extensions, which all do), as with `gettid`.

When calling `recvfrom` in C, the C library calls the kernel to do the syscall.

The `syscall` function is the function that puts the system call number in the `%eax` register and uses `int $0x80`.

The reason you don't see `recvfrom` in https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/ is because https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/ is very, very incomplete.

The reason there are many functions in (3) that you don't see in (2) is because many functions on (3) don't have a system call. They may or may not rely on system calls, they just don't have a system call with that specific name that backs them.

Comment: are functions in (3) calling functions in (2) behind in scenes? why some are named the same

Comment: @josh Everything in 2 is a wrapper around a system call. Everything in 3 is not, but may call the functions from 2 indirectly (say `stdio.h` functions, like `getc` and `printf`, that use `write`). Some have the same names because they may or may not be implemented on top of system calls.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Let's not bring Windows into this.

Comment: If I do `recvfrom` in a C code is it using (2) or (3), how can the other one be used?

Comment: alot of functions are under (3) but not (2), i.e clean. Does this mean these are done by C runtime directly without relying on system calls and the underlying OS?

Comment: @josh No, that just means that these functions do not have a system call equivalent.

Comment: @StaceyGirl May I please explain?

Comment: ok im still confused (why is this so confusing lol), I just tried `pid_t a = gettid();` in a Simple C code and then I got `undefined reference to gettid`. I know `gettid` is not defined in libc but then I thought linux would have the headers? linux doesn't have them either? then why is it documented as `gettid()` in the linux man page?

Comment: @josh `gettid()` is not in the C library, so you cannot call it from C unless you use `syscall(SYS_gettid)`. Linux does not define the functions, it's your C library that allows you to call them. See `NOTES` for more info.

Comment: so then linux itself doesn't actually implement any of the sys call wrappers? it's the job of libc to do it? then why (2) has documented it as if it's implanted in Linux? `gettid() returns the caller's ....`, `gettid()` function doesn't actually exist? why don't they just put the `hex` value of the sys call then, what's the reason behind documenting the function if it doesn't actually exist?

Comment: @josh Exactly. Not all functions in (2) are in the C library. They do exist, but you have to use `syscall` to call them.

Comment: this is so stupid, the manual page has a code example like `#include <sys/types.h> pid_t gettid(void);`, but this function doesn't actually exist! why would they write this then!

Comment: @josh That's just the prototype. It's for reference. You need to include `sys/types.h` and cast the result of `syscall` to `pid_t` to get the correct result.

Comment: I did include `sys/types.h` but it till doesn't compile, so it's just a prototype then? this is horrible documentation.

Comment: @josh As I said, it's just for reference. You have to include `sys/types.h`, `unistd.h`, and `sys/syscall.h` and then use `(pid_t)syscall(SYS_gettid)` to get the correct result.

Comment: @josh I've added an example of how to wrap `gettid` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, functions listed in section `(2)` are *functions*. They are different from functions in section `(3)` in that there is always a system call behind.

Those function will usually do additional work to make them behave like POSIX functions (converting returned value to `-1` and `errno`), or to just make them usable (`clone` syscall requires libc integration to be useful). Sometimes arguments are passed to a system call differently than function prototype suggests, for example they can be packed into a structure and pointer to that structure can be passed through a register.

Sometimes a new syscall is added to fix some issues of the older syscall. In this can a function can be implemented using a new syscall transparently (see `mmap` vs `mmap2`, `sys_select` vs `sys_old_select`).

As for `recvfrom`, socket-related functions are implemented by either [their respective syscalls](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc6/source/net/socket.c) or by a legacy `sys_socketcall`. For example musl still has this code:

```
#ifdef SYS_socket
#define __socketcall(nm,a,b,c,d,e,f) syscall(SYS_##nm, a, b, c, d, e, f)
#define __socketcall_cp(nm,a,b,c,d,e,f) syscall_cp(SYS_##nm, a, b, c, d, e, f)
#else
#define __socketcall(nm,a,b,c,d,e,f) syscall(SYS_socketcall, __SC_##nm, \
    ((long [6]){ (long)a, (long)b, (long)c, (long)d, (long)e, (long)f }))
#define __socketcall_cp(nm,a,b,c,d,e,f) syscall_cp(SYS_socketcall, __SC_##nm, \
    ((long [6]){ (long)a, (long)b, (long)c, (long)d, (long)e, (long)f }))
#endif
```

which tries to use appropriate syscall if available, backing off to `socketcall` otherwise.

Comment: no longer true about `sys_socketcall` -- that's only kept for compatibility, and only on some platforms.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it, so when calling recvfrom in a C code, which on is being called? does one call the other one behind the scenes? which one is the one that actually puts some `hex` code in a register and then calls the `int` instruction to the OS?

Comment: @josh In the past it would call `socketcall` with appropriate [argument](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc6/source/include/uapi/linux/net.h#L28). Now it seems there is a separate syscall for that. So it might do one or another. It depends on libc implementation.

Comment: ... and those platforms are not x86-64, arm-eabi or arm64.

Comment: @mosvy I don't see socketcall [being disabled](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc6/source/net/socket.c) at all. Might be omitted from the table, but the code is still there.

Comment: [look harder](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl)

Comment: Using the link from your comment: `sys_socketcall` is inside [`#ifdef __ARCH_WANT_SYS_SOCKETCALL`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc6/source/net/socket.c#L2718), and that is only defined in legacy architectures, eg. [x86-32](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc6/source/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd.h#L50). On `x86-64` and any newer archs there's simply no such syscall that any C library can fall back to. Also see what the `socketcall(2)` manpage on your system says.

Comment: @mosvy I don't understand why you are referring to x86_32 as some dead architecture. x86_64 kernel still runs 32-bit programs and still has to implement `socketcall`. `__ARCH_WANT_SYS_SOCKETCALL` is defined unconditionally [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc6/source/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd.h#L50).

Comment: @mosvy And x86 in linux is not for x86-32, it is for both x86-32 and x86-64. `socketcall` might be missing from the x86-64 syscall table (as I mentioned above, that was possible), but it is still in the kernel, available only in 32-bit mode.

Comment: tl;dr; please show me a program which builds to a straight x86-64 binary (not a 32 bit one), no matter the library it links against, etc and calls `socketcall(2)`. The i386 system call table contains a lot of compatibility garbage, from `uselib(2)` to `oldolduname(2)` (sic) and `socketcall(2)` joined the club years ago.

Comment: @mosvy And why would I do that? This question is nowhere to be related to x86-64, just a general Linux question. `socketcall` is still there and is still used to to implement socket-related function. Everything in my answer is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198769/discussion-between-staceygirl-and-mosvy).

Comment: Honestly, who cares? It's just an example to explain the difference between system calls and C library functions.

Comment: `socketcall` has been deprecated for x86-32 only in 4.3 which was release in november 2015 - less than 4 years ago. Taking in account time for libc implementations to adapt it, its nowhere close to be considered _long deprecated_.

Answer (score 2):

> exists both under the linux system call

The way userspace programs communicate with kernel is by using [syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) function. All `syscall()` does is push some number on specific registers and then execute a special interrupt instruction. On the interrupt the execution is transferred to kernel, kernel then reads data from userspace using special registers.

Each syscall has a number and different arguments. User space programs are expected to "find out" arguments for each syscall by for example inspecting the documentation.

Linux system call is just a number, like [`__NR_recvfrom`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3-rc6/source/arch/sh/include/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h#L251) which is equal to 231 on x86-64 architecture.

> C Lib function

A C library function is a function implemented by the C library implementation. So, for example glibc implements [recvfrom](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/recvfrom.c#L23) as a simple wrapper around `syscall(__NR_recvfrom, ...)`. This is C interface the library provides programmers to access kernel related functions. So C programmers wouldn't need to read the documentation for each syscall and have nice C interface to call the kernel.

> However I cannot find recvfrom in the above link.

Don't use the link then. At best inspect kernel sources under `uapi` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the info, so which one is the function that actually pushes some number on specific registers? the Kernel function or the C function? is one calling the other one behind the scenes? why are the named the same?

Comment: Both? That would be architecture dependent? `syscall` C function pushes data to registers to let kernel know which syscall it calls and it also pushes arguments. Kernel pushes the return value of the syscall to registers. Then switches the execution context back to userspace. But `syscall` itself is just a C interface - it has to be implemented in machine instructions (assembly), you have to call [`int`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_(x86_instruction))

Comment: `is one calling the other one behind the scenes?` - I don't understand. Once the execution transfers to kernel, it goes back to userspace once the syscall is completed. Asynchronous notification are transferred to userspace via signals, ex. [`aio_write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/aio_write.3.html). (In "regular" operations:) Kernel doesn't "call" userspace programs. Use space calls kernel. Kernel can raise a signal in userspace programs. `why are the named the same?` - to avoid confusion? You would name a C function same as a syscall number it represents.

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at `recvfrom` as an example, this function exists both as a Linux system call as well as a C library function.

I was able to find 2 pages for `recvfrom`:

- [recvfrom(2) in Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvfrom.2.html)
- [recvfrom(3p) in POSIX Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/recvfrom.3p.html)

Often, the Linux page also tells how Linux version of the function differs from POSIX one.

> They are different from functions in section (3) in that there is always a system call behind [section 2].

Not necessarily. Section 2 is Linux-specific API for user-space applications. Linus Torvalds insists that user-space applications must never be broken because of Linux kernel API changes. `glibc` or another library normally implement the functions, to maintain the stable user-space API and delegate to the kernel.